# Inherit just the javascript code from a master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

So I have a Javascript function on my master page. It works fine when I call it from pages that derive from this master page, however, on pages that don't, it obviously doesn't work. I am not able to put it in another .js file either because it uses some embedded c# code in it, so it has to be within a `<script>` tag.

This is the function:

```
function GridExport(viewUrl, fileName)
    {
        var actionUrl = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/ExportToExcel")%>";
        var guid = GetGUIDValue();
        window.open((actionUrl + "?id=" + guid + "&viewName=" + viewUrl + "&fileName="  + fileName), null, null, null);
    }
```

is there a way I can just include the Javascript definitions from my master page in another view without deriving from the master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `UserControl` containing this `<script>` or abstract out the `actionUrl` to a parameter of the `GridExport` function

```
function GridExport(viewUrl, fileName, actionUrl)
{
    var guid = GetGUIDValue();
    window.open((actionUrl + "?id=" + guid + "&viewName=" + viewUrl + "&fileName="  + fileName), null, null, null);
}
```

---

Another handy way to avoid this path problem would be to have a global variable to define the root of the site:

```
var root = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/") %>";
```

then your function could always use this variable and append what it needs:

```
function GridExport(viewUrl, fileName)
{
    var actionUrl = root + "mvc/Indications.cfc/ExportToExcel";
    var guid = GetGUIDValue();
    window.open((actionUrl + "?id=" + guid + "&viewName=" + viewUrl + "&fileName="  + fileName), null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Master pages can be embedded within each other.  Why not just make a master page with only your javascript in it.  Then make another master page that has the javascript master page as it's master.  When creating new pages you can choose which one to use.

MasterPage1 -> Just javascript

MasterPage2 -> Contains your other stuff and has MasterPage1 as it's master

If you just want the javascript then user MasterPage1, for everything else user MasterPage2.